# Trunc() fails for high Int64 for 64-bit builds

Tags: delphi, 64-bit

Why does the following code fail for 64-bit builds (but works for 32-bit builds)?

```
var
  TruncTmp: Extended;
begin
  TruncTmp := 9223372036854775296;
  TruncTmp := Trunc(TruncTmp); // this fails on 64-bit
  Assert(TruncTmp = 9223372036854775296);
end;
```

> First chance exception at $0000000000405D70. Exception class $C0000090 with message 'c0000090 FLOAT_INVALID_OPERATION'.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Notes:

- I am using Delphi 10.2
- Numbers < `9223372036854775296` work fine

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no "extended" (80-bit FP) type under Win64 - it is just an alias to "double" (64-bit FP). So you only have 53-bit of resolution in double.

So my guess it is that is as expected in your case.

Comment: Thanks. Now I found the info in RAD Studio Docs: [System.Extended](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Extended)

Comment: To be precise, the value stored is actually 9223372036854775808, which is larger than what can be stored in an INT64 (=9223372036854775807).

Comment: @UweRaabe: that is actually the real cause for the invalid operation exception. This is of course the result of the fact that only 53 bits are available for the precision.

Comment: This is reason for precision loss, not for exception